# Does Rust have anything similar to CallerMembrerName in C#

Tags: rust

I'd like to know the name of the function that called my function in Rust.

In C# there's [`CallerMemberName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-6.0#examples) attribute which tells the compiler to replace the value of a string argument to which it's applied with the name of the caller.

Does Rust have anything like that?

Comment: https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/backend/implicit-caller-location.html

Comment: WOW. I'm not a Rust beginner, but I would have 100% answered that this does not exists and I'm certain. Learned something today.

Comment: That's pretty amazing, but I was looking for the name of the function, which called my function, which is different from the file name and line number.

Comment: Again, my gut feeling says no, definitely not, but maybe someone proves me wrong again? I mean, there is method resolution when printing stack traces ...

Comment: In C# it's resolved at compile time. And when it's called from the closure/lambda etc. it seems to print the name of the method where the closure was passed. For example https://dotnetfiddle.net/xDc1gK . It's not supported in most languages, AFAIK, I was just wondering whether I can do something like that. I can be useful for monitoring etc.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's impossible to be resolved at compile time in Rust. When they get compiled, they have absolutely no knowledge about the functions that will call them. That knowledge only gets filled in at link time. And then the bytecode won't get modified any more.

Comment: You can emulate C#'s behavior using macros. `#[track_caller]` is works similarly too, but doesn't provide access to the function name.

Comment: As Chayim is saying, this should be doable with macros. Here is a crate that appears to implement such a macro, I haven't looked at how it works but I imagine it's not too hard to follow: https://crates.io/crates/function_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a compile time solution, but you can use the backtrace functionality to resolve it at runtime.

```rust
use backtrace::Backtrace;

fn caller_name_slow() -> Option<String> {
    let backtrace = Backtrace::new();
    let symbolname = backtrace.frames().get(2)?.symbols().first()?.name();
    symbolname.map(|s| format!("{:#?}", s))
}

fn caller_name_fast() -> Option<String> {
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut result = None;

    backtrace::trace({
        |frame| {
            count += 1;
            if count == 5 {
                // Resolve this instruction pointer to a symbol name
                backtrace::resolve_frame(frame, |symbol| {
                    if let Some(name) = symbol.name() {
                        result = Some(format!("{:#?}", name));
                    }
                });
                false
            } else {
                true // keep going to the next frame
            }
        }
    });

    result
}

fn my_function() {
    println!("I got called by '{}'.", caller_name_slow().unwrap());
    println!("I got called by '{}'.", caller_name_fast().unwrap());
}

fn main() {
    my_function();
}
```

```
I got called by 'rust_tmp::main'.
I got called by 'rust_tmp::main'.
```

Note, however, that his is unreliable. The amount of stack frames we have to go up differs between targets and release/debug (due to inlining). For example, on my machine, in release I had to modify `count == 5` to `count == 2`.

Comment: Note this is also _very_ expensive, so don't do that in the hot path.